# SharePoint Integration with SalesForce

Tags: infopath-data-connections, sharepoint-integration

I have a document library that contains info path forms in SharePoint 2013. Is it possible to populate a field in an info-path form with information from a field in SalesForce? 
I know you can create a data connection from an external source on a field, but  can you create connections on a library as well as a field in the form?

**For example:** If a user creates a form in sales force with a field named "id" i need to grab that data and populate the corresponding field in info path within that document library.